# Bash: remove spaces in directory name

Tags: shell-script, find, directory, rename

**!! This question is not about SHELL, it's about BASH, can't change the faulty tag !!**

I've got a code that removes the spaces in directories and filenames (and inserts a dot);

```
find $jdir -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /./g' "{}" \;
```

let's say $jdir = "test files are here"

This code don't rename the $jdir.

and I can't set it to the parent directory, because then it would rename a lot of other directories.

How do I get it to rename the $jdir?

(testing bug? in forum, disregard this line)
I can't change the tags, a bug in the forum?

Comment: well, maybe, @Siva but I need change the first directory also, not all files and directories in that directory...

Comment: @Kamil sorry for confusing you, this is about bash, not shell, the forum don't let me change the faulty shell-tag

Comment: Bash is a shell. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) explicitly mentions `bash`. Your code works for me, if only `$jdir` is properly double-quoted.

Comment: @Kamil oh, thought shell and bash was two different shells.. well, newbies you know...  but my code only fixes the files and directories inside $jdir, not the $jdir itself.. or does it do that for you?

Comment: It does. The directory gets renamed to `test.files.are.here`. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS; `find` (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git.

Comment: @Kamil oh, found it.. it was actually both double-qoute and the end-slash that was messing it up!

Comment: .. now I just need a way to get the new "main directory" to a variable, since the old one don't exist anymore.. got any suggestion?

Comment: @JoBe `jdir=${jdir// /.}` would replace all spaces by dots in the value of the variable `jdir`.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you, that solved that issue!